# emacs scheme racket auto reload file

Tags: emacs, scheme, racket, reload

I am new to scheme, but was able to get it running in emacs. I like having the file open in one buffer in emacs, and having the racket interpreter open in another so that I can test as I'm writing etc.  The problem is that every time I want to test something I have to save the file (not a big deal) and then reload it in the interpreter using (enter! "programname").

Is there anyway to have it auto reload every time I save the file? It gets to be really tedious having to reload the file manually every time I change something, especially because I'm still learning scheme so I have to go back and forth to make changes a LOT. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geiser and/or Quack are very nice modes for Emacs. Using DrRacket is also a great option.

But to more-literally answer your question:

You could add the following to your `.emacs` and bind it to the F5 key for a rough approximation of DrRacket's *Run* command:

```
(defun run-roughly-like-dr-racket ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((w (selected-window)))
    (set-buffer-modified-p t)           ;force save buffer so that enter! ...
    (save-buffer)                       ;...will re-evaluate

    (other-window -1)
    (run-scheme)
    (select-window w)

    (comint-send-string (get-buffer-process "*scheme*")
                        (format "(enter! \"%s\")\n" (buffer-file-name)))

    (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-process "*scheme*") t)
    (select-window w)))
```

Comment: @molbdnilo :p I liked your answer and up-voted it, in addition to posting mine.

Comment: Haha, somebody deleted the comment where I referred to @molbdnilo as "that other loser". Well done, SO.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thou shalt not self-deprecate? o_O

Answer (score 3):

The most useful option is probably [Geiser](http://geiser.nongnu.org).

It lets you, among other splendid things, compile the current file with a keystroke, or only evaluate the definition at point.
It's well documented and is the closest to a SLIME for Scheme you can get, I think.

If you can live without Emacs, DrRacket is also an excellent environment to work in.